# Chrome Webix .setValue() not working consistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webix

On Chrome, .setValue("") doesn't always clear the visible value.

With webix:

```
webix.ui({
    cols:[
        { view:"text", id:"message", placeholder:"Type chat here..."},
        { view:"button", value: "Send", click:send_message, width:75 }
    ]
});


function send_message(){
    var text = $$("message").getValue();
    if (text)
    {
        //send text to chat
    }
    $$("message").setValue(""); //Should set text field data to blank.
    $$("message").refresh();
    $$("message").focus();
}
```

On Firefox, when I hit [Enter] after typing a message, `send_message` posts the message to the chat and clears the text field. In Chrome, the text field does not always clear. The old message text lingers in the field. The cursor, however, jumps to the start of the text.

I can't figure out why Chrome is acting this way.

Comment: The same code works for me - http://webix.com/snippet/9d6ba1a0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. Not sure why, but setting a hotkey for the button fixed the issue.

```
 { view:"button", value: "Send", click:send_message, width:75, hotkey:"enter" }
```

Now hitting enter works as well as clicking the button in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: adding the enter hotkey may result in double triggering the send_message function, which somehow resolves the issue